# Can't use sample_weights both for fit or evaluate model on Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I need to set sample_weights parameter for training a unbalanced classes on Keras.

If I try to use a list of weights it gives a error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

If I try to use a 1D array, it gives the error:
ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (17,) for an input with shape (180, 17). sample_weight cannot be broadcast.

```
model.evaluate(X, Y, batch_size=50, sample_weight=weights)
```

In the end of the day, any way I tried to pass this parameters it gives some error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need weights shaped as `(180,)`. One weight per sample in the training data.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter is class_weight, that accepts a dictionary of weights.

```
weights = dict([0:1, 1:2, 2:1, 3:5])
model.evaluate(X, Y, batch_size=50, class_weight=weights)
```